# How to store PHP page with variables in DB for email use?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question that someone may think sounds quite stupid, but I'm not a professional developer, just studying, the situation is following.

I'm developing the email system for my site, where I send emails on registration, updates to profile etc. I store the whole body of email in the MySQL DB.

When the user registers I invoke the following function:

```
function emailsend($category){
$db=new db();

$embodysql=$db->query("SELECT * FROM emailsys WHERE id=?","$category")->fetchArray();
$embody=$embodysql['body'];

echo "Получили $embody";

$fp=fopen("../emails/emailsent.php", "w") or die("Не могу открыть файл");
fwrite($fp, $embody);
fclose ($fp);
```

As you may notice I write to the emailsent.php contents that I plan to send to the user later. However, I can't figure out, how do I process the contents of the body field in my DB that contains records like $name, $fname. I can pass these arguments when calling on the function, but how to do I tell PHP processor to replace these variables with real values before writing to file and after reading from DB. The example of DB record is following:

```
<div class="body-text" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;text-align:left;color:#333333">
<?php
echo"$name $fname";?>Добро пожаловать в <a href="https://ikeen.com">Школу Айкин</a> - место, где вы получите современные и понятные знания, которые сможете применять сразу после обучения.<br><br>
Ваш логин:<?php echo"$login"?>
<br><br>
</div>
```

At what exact stage after reading the contents from DB and creating the file and how do I process those variables?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `"$category"`  why the quotes?

Comment: Specific DB library, that converts this structure to prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to write $name and $fname while writing to the file.

There are 2 methods that come to my mind first

1. If you send value to the emailsend($category) function;

emailsend ($category, $name, $fname)

$date = date("YmdHis"); // I added

$Embody = $date. "\t". $name. "\t". $fname. "\t". $ Embodysql['body'];

2. $name and $fname are saved in the session.

$date = date("YmdHis"); // I added

$ Embody = $date. "\t". $_SESSION["name"]. "\t". $_SESSION ["fname"]. "\t". $ Embodysql['body'];

Comment: Not exactly I want to change these variables in the string that I get from the DB, I store the whole contents of the file there. So to change stored variables as if user opened the URL.

Comment: Is there a $ name and $ fname in the emailsys table? Or can you access it when you join with emailsys?

Comment: It is IN the field stored as text

Comment: So far I have decided to go the simpliest way through str_replace, I think it will eat a litlle more resources though